# Maven - Best Practice Production Classpath/Jar Organisation? (Non-WAR/EAR)

Tags: java, maven, jar, production

Simple console maven artifacts with shared dependencies (some also provide public API's in addition to their own class) living on same production server. How to best organise/install on production server?

My instinct is for a single folder holding all (version numbered) jars (ie. a 'flattened'/dependency populated 'repository') however:

(a) Can't see how such a folder would increase, on a 'dependency' basis, it's population from maven deployment repository

(b) How a jar's manifest's classpath would change from the default 'lib/...,lib/...' (ie. relative to 'main' jar, sensible for dev/test using Eclipse) to just '...,...'

What is recommended best practice as regards organisation on production server?

Google'ing 'maven production classpath' (amongst others) resulted in http://blog.armstrongconsulting.com/?p=232 which seems related but light on detail.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

How experienced are you with Maven? If you are the process described in the blog you mention is pretty straightforward also without going into details.

Re (a): Dependencies are downloaded from a remote Maven repository into a local Maven repository on demand. Default in `${user.home}/.m2/repository` or according to `<localRepository>` at the beginning of your `settings.xml`. See [Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html). So, there's no need for a single 'flattened'/dependency populated 'repository' folder.

A local repository can also be populated with the `install:install-file` goal manually. But this can be a cumbersome process if there are many artifacts to install.

See [Maven, Available Plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) for what the mentioned plugin:goals do.

Comment: Relatively experienced in terms of standard dev/test lifecycle but obviously missing something as the blog doesn't launch me into implementation ;)

Your repository description is accurate but means little to me in terms of the production 'installation' - ie. resolving jars via classpath (ideally within manifest) for 'java -jar ...' on the production server.